# Synology NAS: Bad sector warning, but drive passes all S.M.A.R.T. tests and IronWolf tests. Replace?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, bad-sectors, synology-diskstation, replacement

I have a Synology NAS and received a warning that "Bad sectors on Drive 12 have increased." I ran the quick S.M.A.R.T. test and the IronWolf (Seagate brand) health test and both say that the drive is healthy. Wondering if the Synology OS is able to "rope off" bad sectors and the drive can continue to be kept in service or if I should replace the drive now? Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Did you look at the full SMART report, or just the status?

Comment: I mean, the full report may show a few bad sectors, which is acceptable on any drive, so the status can still be OK/Healthy. What is important is the growing rate of the bad sectors: if the number is stable then you don't need to worry, but if it's rapidly increasing you'd better replace the drive.

Comment: Thank you PierU! I have not run a full SMART report but will do that next. I'm betting it will need to be replaced as the first warning I got said that bad sectors were at 16 and now they are at 41 a few days later. Regardless, thanks for you for answering.